# Exporting mongoose model within a npm package

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, mongoose

I have a npm package using locally with npm link.

This is how my model looks like

```
// User.ts
import mongoose, { Schema, model, Document } from 'mongoose'

interface IUser extends Document {
  name: string
  created_at: Date
  updated_at: Date
}

const userSchema = new Schema<IUser>(
  {
  name: { type: String, required: true }
}, {
  timestamps: true
})

export default mongoose.model<IUser>('User', userSchema)
```

Still in my package i have a index to export all my models like this:

```
// index.ts
export { default as User } from './models/User'
```

Now within my project using this package im doing something like this:

```
// New project using the package via npm link
import { User } from 'tbmlib'
```

I cant really tell you what isnt working. I cant create a document. If i print `User` im getting: `Model { User }`

Any ideas?